# Масштабируемость видео

Tags: html5, видео

Как обстоят дела с поддержкой `html5 video` разными браузерами? Сушествует ли до сих под эта проблема. Не могу найти современной информации.

Задача: Что бы при изменении размеров окна браузера, динамически уменьшалось окно видео.
Сейчас я использую mediaelementplayer js. Процентные величины он не принимает. Точнее он принимает их при создании элемента, а после он не меняет величины. Пытался вставить костыль, что бы менять размеры отталкиваясь от `$(window).resize();` но не всё так просто. Если и внести туда изменения ширины то в элементе embed видео становиться обрубленным, т.е. ширина элемента меняется а картинка в нём нет.

Есть ли варианты как обойти embed? или другие варианты использования плагинов ил тому подобное.

Буду рад любой информации. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Всё хорошо.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=video)
2. Для всех подобных объектов для растягивания и сжатия можно прописать размеры в css.

Comment: Переделал свой костыль под css. Размер динамически вообще не изменяется. Если через `$(window).resize();` то размер меняться но содержимое `embed` нет.

Пример:
http://take.ms/i53To
Зелёным - область `embed`. Красным то что отображается в этом тэге.

Comment: Я говорил не про `embed`, а про `video`. И ни через какой-то resize, а через css.

Comment: @Ford, http://jsfiddle.net/y6qk9a5k/

Comment: @Ford, http://jsfiddle.net/y6qk9a5k/1/ - немного улучшил.

Comment: Начал переделывать на html5. В вашем примере видео воспроизводится. Начал пробовать, видео не воспроизводится. Копировал даже ваш код в чистую страницу. Можете дать наводку в чём может быть причина?

Comment: @Ford, атрибут autoplay и правильность формата. Посмотри, какие браузеры какие видео умеют воспроизводить и размести все требуемые форматы.